# Hello guys, Has anyone used the evaluation scripts provided in RGBDSLAM_v2 with the .bag files obtained directly from the package GUI?

Tags: ros, rgbdslam-v2, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying with this comand: ./run_tests.sh [rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]
And I got this:

[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
Evaluating ORB
Will evaluate RGBD-SLAM on the following bagfiles:
ORB_home_newcalibpar.bag rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk.bag rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag
[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
14:34:31 Results for ORB_home_newcalibpar are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/ORB_home_newcalibpar
14:34:33 Finished processing ORB_home_newcalibpar
mv: cannot stat ‘ORB_home_newcalibpar.bag?*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘ORB_home_newcalibpar-groundtruth.txt’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/test/test_settings.launch’: No such file or directory
[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
14:34:33 Results for rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk
14:34:33 Finished processing rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk
mv: cannot stat ‘rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk.bag?*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk-groundtruth.txt’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/test/test_settings.launch’: No such file or directory
[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
14:34:33 Results for rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz
14:34:33 Finished processing rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz
mv: cannot stat ‘rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag?*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz-groundtruth.txt’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/test/test_settings.launch’: No such file or directory
./run_tests.sh: line 70: //rgbd_benchmark/summarize_evaluation.sh: No such file or directory
elizeu@elizeu:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test$ rosrun rgbdslam summarize_evaluation.sh /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz
[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
elizeu@elizeu:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test$ ./run_tests.sh [rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag][rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
Evaluating ORB
Will evaluate RGBD-SLAM on the following bagfiles:
ORB_home_newcalibpar.bag rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk.bag rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag
[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
14:52:42 Results for ORB_home_newcalibpar are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/ORB_home_newcalibpar
14:52:42 Finished processing ORB_home_newcalibpar
mv: cannot stat ‘ORB_home_newcalibpar.bag?*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘ORB_home_newcalibpar-groundtruth.txt’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/test/test_settings.launch’: No such file or directory
[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
14:52:42 Results for rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk
14:52:42 Finished processing rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk
mv: cannot stat ‘rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk.bag?*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk-groundtruth.txt’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/test/test_settings.launch’: No such file or directory
[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
14:52:42 Results for rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz
14:52:42 Finished processing rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz
mv: cannot stat ‘rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag?*’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz-groundtruth.txt’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/test/test_settings.launch’: No such file or directory
[rospack] Error: package 'rgbdslam' not found
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk ... No estimate at level  0
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz ... No estimate at level  0

paste: eval_translational.ate.txt: No such file or directory
ATE Results at Level 0 are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/maxate_evaluation_0.csv
600 Features      "ATE MAX"        "Duration"        "Optimization Time"        Nodes  Edges
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk ... No estimate at level  1
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz ... No estimate at level  1

paste: eval_translational.ate.txt: No such file or directory
ATE Results at Level 1 are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/maxate_evaluation_1.csv
600 Features      "ATE MAX"        "Duration"        "Optimization Time"        Nodes  Edges
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk ... No estimate at level  2
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz ... No estimate at level  2

paste: eval_translational.ate.txt: No such file or directory
ATE Results at Level 2 are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/maxate_evaluation_2.csv
600 Features      "ATE MAX"        "Duration"        "Optimization Time"        Nodes  Edges
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk ... No estimate at level  3
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz ... No estimate at level  3

paste: eval_translational.ate.txt: No such file or directory
ATE Results at Level 3 are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/maxate_evaluation_3.csv
600 Features      "ATE MAX"        "Duration"        "Optimization Time"        Nodes  Edges
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_desk ... No estimate at level  4
rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz ... No estimate at level  4

paste: eval_translational.ate.txt: No such file or directory
ATE Results at Level 4 are stored in /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test/[rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag]/emm__0.00/CANDIDATES_4/RANSAC_100/OPT_SKIP_10/ORB/600_Features/maxate_evaluation_4.csv
600 Features      "ATE MAX"        "Duration"        "Optimization Time"        Nodes  Edges
elizeu@elizeu:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test$ /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigoclear
bash: /home/elizeu/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigoclear: No such file or directory
elizeu@elizeu:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src/rgbdslam_v2-indigo/test$ clear

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248083/hello-guys,-has-anyone-used-the-evaluation-scripts-provided-in-rgbdslam_v2-with-the-.bag-files-obtained-directly-from-the-package-gui?/) by [elizeu_jr](https://answers.ros.org/users/27322/elizeu_jr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first (and possibly only) problem is `package 'rgbdslam' not found`. This means that ROS does not know about the rgbdslam package. This problem has been [asked](http://answers.ros.org/question/199940/getting-package-not-found-error/) [before](http://answers.ros.org/question/190317/ros-cant-find-package/).

If you have rgbdslam in a catkin workspace somewhere, make sure you have built it (with `catkin_make install`) and sourced it (with `source path/to/workspace/devel/setup.bash`).

If that error goes away and it still doesn't work, the bag/ground truth files may be in the wrong place. The error should tell you somewhere!

---

Originally posted by [petern3](https://answers.ros.org/users/28607/petern3/) with karma: 186 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0